# Add the '-' in the phone number, along with the ext

Tags: ruby, phone-number

I need a way to add the '-' into a phone number, verify that it is the correct length, add parenthesis around the area code, and default to nil if no extension is given. For example:

```
9876542123 ext: 6789 -> Should end up -> (987)654-2123 ext: 6789
4543456 -> should fail
9876785678 ext: -> should end up -> (987)678-5678
```

How can I do this without a regular expression?

What I've attempted:

```
def format_phone_number(num)
  num.insert(0, '(').insert(-3, ')').insert(-4, '-')
end
```

Outputs:

```
(12345678-)94
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deal with the side-effect that you are changing the size of the string on each call to `insert`:

```
def format_phone_number(num)
  num.insert(0, '(')
  puts num                       #=> (9876785678
  puts num.size                  #=> 11
  num.insert(4, ')')
  puts num                       #=> (987)6785678
  puts num.size                  #=> 12
  num.insert(8, '-')
  puts num                       #=> (987)678-5678 
  puts num.size                  #=> 13 
end

format_phone_number("9876785678")
```

To handle phone numbers of less than 10 characters, you could `raise` an exception:

```
def format_phone_number(num)
  raise "Less than 10 chars" if num.size < 10
  num.insert(0, '(').insert(4, ')').insert(8, '-')
end

format_phone_number "9876785678"            #=> (987)654-2123   
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext: 6789"  #=> (987)654-2123 ext: 6789
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext:"       #=> (987)654-2123 ext: 
format_phone_number "987678567"             #=> in `format_phone_number': Less than 10 chars (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: OOOOH! That makes a lot more sense, alright thank you!

Comment: It's good that you checks if there are fewer than 10 characters, but that's only one among many potential problems. For example, if `num = "987678567800000000X0"` this returns `"(987)678-567800000000X0"`. If `num = "9876542123 xet: 3S4"`, it returns `(987)654-2123 xet: 3S4"`.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland: Agreed.  I just wanted to demo a simple approach for checking invalid input.

Answer (score 2):

This question nicely illustrates the benefit of using regular expressions for these types of problems. Let's compare a method that employs a regex with one that does not, for the same level of functionality (as embodied in the examples).

**Use a regular expression**

```
R = /
    \A                  # match beginning of string
    (\d{3})             # match 3 digits in capture group 1
    (\d{3})             # match 3 digits in capture group 2
    (\d{4})             # match 3 digits in capture group 3
    (                   # begin capture group 4 
      \sext:            # match space, string
      (?:\s\d+)?        # optionally match space, >= 1 digits in non-capture group
      \z                # match end of string
      |                 # or
      \z                # match end of string
    )                   # end capture group 4
    /x                  # free-spacing regex definition mode

def format_phone_number(num)
  return nil unless (num.strip) =~ R
  ext = ($4 == " ext:") ? '' : $4
  "(%s)%s-%s%s" % [$1, $2, $3, ext]
end

format_phone_number "9876542123 ext: 6789"  #=> "(987)654-2123 ext: 6789" 
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext: 6789 " #=> "(987)654-2123 ext: 6789" 
format_phone_number "9876785678 ext:"       #=> "(987)678-5678" 
format_phone_number "9876785678"            #=> "(987)678-5678" 
format_phone_number "4543456"               #=> nil 
format_phone_number "#9876785678"           #=> nil 
format_phone_number "98765421234 ext: 6789" #=> nil 
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext.: 6789" #=> nil 
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext:6789"   #=> nil 
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext: 6789#" #=> nil 
format_phone_number "9876542123ext: 6789"   #=> nil
```

**Don't use a regular expression**

```
def format_phone_number(num)
  str = num.strip
  return nil if str.size < 10
  nbr, ext = str[0,10], str[10..-1]
  ext = "" if ext == " ext:"
  return nil unless (Integer(nbr) rescue false)
  return nil unless ext.empty? || ext[0,6] == " ext: "
  return nil unless (ext.empty? || (Integer(ext[6..-1]) rescue false))
  "(%s)%s-%s%s" % [num[0,3], num[3,3], num[6,4], ext]
end

format_phone_number "9876542123 ext: 6789"  #=> "(987)654-2123 ext: 6789" 
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext: 6789 " #=> "(987)654-2123 ext: 6789" 
format_phone_number "9876785678 ext:"       #=> "(987)678-5678" 
format_phone_number "9876785678"            #=> "(987)678-5678" 
format_phone_number "4543456"               #=> nil 
format_phone_number "#9876785678"           #=> nil 
format_phone_number "98765421234 ext: 6789" #=> nil 
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext.: 6789" #=> nil 
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext:6789"   #=> nil 
format_phone_number "9876542123 ext: 6789#" #=> nil 
format_phone_number "9876542123ext: 6789"   #=> nil
```

Comment: That's great and all but it doesn't help me insert the information into the phone numbers, it just requires it.

Comment: As I understand, you merely want to format the string in a particular way. You don't have to use `String#insert` for that.

Answer (score 1):

The following should closely resemble what you're looking for. When you insert a character into a string then you have to remember that you're increasing the length of the string by 1. Also, using a negative index with insert, inserts the character at position `num.length - index`.

```
def format_phone_number(num)
  if num.length >= 10
    num.insert(0, '(').insert(4, ')').insert(8, '-')
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what you want to return if the phone number is not the appropriate length.

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome I don't have a testing environment at hand. I thought it was `9` but I guess it's `8`.

Comment: format_phone_number("9876785678 ext:") #=> "(987)678-5678 ext:", but it should be "(987)678-5678)".

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why, but this worked:

```
def format_phone_number(num)
  num.insert(0, '(').insert(4, ')').insert(8, '-')
end
```

When I input:

```
1234567894 -> (123)456-7894
```